# Password Reset Not Sending Emails

Tags: email, forgot-password

My login suddenly stopped working, despite me using the same credentials and not having changed them. So, I have tried to reset my password by going thru the "forgotten password" process. I get this from EE:

> If this email address is associated with an account, instructions for
>   resetting your password have just been emailed to you.

I receive no emails. I tried password resetting another account; also no emails. Checked spam, too.

The site was recently copied over from one hosting to another. Is there anything in the EE database that stores hosting specific mail configuration when initially installed? Perhaps that might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were logged in on the site at the old host when the database backup was taken it could be that the new site thinks you're still logged in. If you then have the security preference to allow only one login at a time for each account this could  stop you logging in.

The fix for this would be to look in the exp_sessions table and remove any rows in there for your member ID.

You may also want to switch the login method from sessions to cookies (or vice versa) and see if that helps. You can do this via your config file.

The reset email may not arrive for a number of reasons. It could be a misconfiguration, improper credentials, or simply a spam filtering issue. I'd crack the login problem first then look at the email problem second. Examine the server logs and maybe use a transactional service such as Mandrill so you can see what's happening to the emails.

Comment: I cannot log into EE. I've deleted all rows in `exp_sessions`. I can see my member details in `exp_members`: `username`, `email`, etc. I'm entering the right username/email on login page. I think I might have forgotten my password. Unfortunately, with the email notification not working, I'm a bit lost as how I can login!

Comment: When I enter my email address in the "Forget Password" page and submit, I see an entry made in `exp_reset_password` for my member id (1).

Comment: I made another member a super admin by editing `exp_members`, asked that member to login, changed my member's password, then was able to log in as myself. I then setup Mandrill. All working now.